# Building blank XML tags with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to build up an XML document using Nokogiri.  Everything is pretty standard so far; most of my code just looks something like:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    ...
    xml.Tag1(object.attribute_1)
    xml.Tag2(object.attribute_2)
    xml.Tag3(object.attribute_3)
    xml.Tag4(nil)
  end

builder.to_xml
```

However, that results in a tag like `<Tag4/>` instead of `<Tag4></Tag4>`, which is what my end user has specified that the output needs to be.

How do I tell Nokogiri to put full tags around a nil value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SaveOptions](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node/SaveOptions.html)::NO_EMPTY_TAGS will get you what you want.

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.blah(nil)
end

puts 'broken:'
puts builder.to_xml
puts 'fixed:'
puts builder.to_xml(save_with: Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_EMPTY_TAGS)
```

output:

```
(511)-> ruby derp.rb 
broken:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<blah/>
fixed:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<blah></blah>
```