# Create non-self-closed empty tag with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

When I try to create an XML document with Nokogiri::XML::Builder:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.my_tag({key: :value})
end
```

I get the following XML tag:

```
<my_tag key="value"/>
```

It is self-closed, but I need the full form:

```
<my_tag key="value"></my_tag>
```

When I pass a value inside the node (or even a space):

```
xml.my_tag("content", key: :value)
xml.my_tag(" ", key: :value)
```

It generates the full tag:

```
<my_tag key="value">content</my_tag>
<my_tag key="value"> </my_tag>
```

But if I pass either an empty string or `nil`, or even an empty block:

```
xml.my_tag("", key: :value)
```

It generates a self-closed tag:

```
<my_tag key="value"/>
```

I believe there should be some attribute or something else that helps me but simple Googling didn't find the answer.

I found a possible solution in "[Building blank XML tags with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685801/building-blank-xml-tags-with-nokogiri)" but it saves all tags as non-self-closed.

Comment: According to the spec, `<foo />` is the same as `<foo></foo>`, the only difference is one is shorter and cleaner. Why must you have the second form? Is it a requirement or a desire? Since XML files can be huge, being able to use the shorter form can result in smaller files when you get into millions of lines.

Comment: As I answered below the reason is in the API. It requires full tags notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Nokogiri's `NO_EMPTY_TAGS` [save option](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node/SaveOptions). (XML calls self-closing tags [empty-element tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags).)

```rb
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.my_tag({key: :value})
end

puts builder.to_xml(save_with: Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_EMPTY_TAGS)
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<my_tag key="value"></my_tag>
```

Each of the options is represented in a bit, so you can mix and match the ones you want. For example, setting `NO_EMPTY_TAGS` by itself will leave your XML on one line without spacing or indentation. If you still want it formatted for humans, you can bitwise or (`|`) it with the `FORMAT` option.

```rb
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.my_tag({key: :value}) do |my_tag|
    my_tag.nested({another: :value})
  end
end

puts builder.to_xml(
  save_with: Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_EMPTY_TAGS
)
puts
puts builder.to_xml(
  save_with: Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_EMPTY_TAGS |
             Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::FORMAT
)
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<my_tag key="value"><nested another="value"></nested></my_tag>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<my_tag key="value">
  <nested another="value"></nested>
</my_tag>
```

There are also a handful of `DEFAULT_*` options at the end of the list that already combine options into common uses.

Your update mentions "it saves all tags as non-self-closed", as if perhaps you only want this single tag instance to be non-self-closed, and the rest to self close. Nokogiri won't produce an inconsistent document like that, but if you must, you can concatenate some XML strings together that you built with different options.

Comment: I use this solution as temporary for now. The problem is that all empty tags are either self-closed or not. But for my corner case it is ok. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why must only this one tag not be self-closed?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure exactly if it is needed. I need full closed tag for compatibility with an API. I'll check it. For now current solution is ok.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably what you want. If the API doesn't like a self-closed tag here, it won't like it elsewhere either. I've worked with plenty that behave that way.